# MDI window and QSignalMapper basics

Tags: c++, qt

First of all my apologies for big looking question but indeed it's not. I’m reading Foundation of qt development book and while reading fourth chapter author tells the basics of MDI window by showing this example :

```
MdiWindow::MdiWindow( QWidget *parent ) : QMainWindow( parent ) {
  setWindowTitle( tr( "MDI" ) );
  QWorkspace* workspace = new QWorkspace;
  setCentralWidget( workspace );
  connect( workspace, SIGNAL(windowActivated(QWidget *)), this, SLOT(enableActions()));
  QSignalMapper* mapper = new QSignalMapper( this );

  //my problem is in this line
  connect( mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget*)), workspace, SLOT(setActiveWindow(QWidget*)) );

  createActions();
  createMenus();
  createToolbars();
  statusBar()->showMessage( tr("Done") );
  enableActions();
}
```

His this para of explanation completely eluded me (is it me or others having problem understanding it too?) :

> Next, a signal mapping object called QSignalMapper is created and
>   connected. A signal mapper is used to tie the source of the signal to
>   an argument of another signal. In this example, the action of the menu
>   item corresponding to each window in the Window menu is tied to the
>   actual document window. The actions are in turn connected to mapper.
>   When the triggered signal is emitted by the action, the sending action
>   has been associated with the QWidget* of the corresponding document
>   window. This pointer is used as the argument in the mapped(QWidget*)
>   signal emitted by the signal mapping object.

**My question** : I still don’t get what is signal mapper class, how it’s used and what's functionality it's doing in the example above?. Can anyone please explain the above para using easy terms? also It’d be awesome if you could please teach me about mapper class’s basics with simple example? possibly in layman’s term?

**P.S** : A confusion is when we have MDI window, do menu changes (though actions are disabled/enabled) e.g suppose for one particular document we have menu “File/close” and for other document we have “File/remaper” ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your last "P.S."? I didn't get what your question was in that paragraph.

Comment: For each and every Qt question, [Qt's excellent documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html) is usually the best starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QSignalMapper` is used to re-emit signals with optional parameters. In other words (from the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html)):

> This class collects a set of parameterless signals, and re-emits them
>   with integer, string or widget parameters corresponding to the object
>   that sent the signal.

A good example (also from the doc - take a look at it) is set as follows:

> Suppose we want to create a custom widget that contains a
>   group of buttons (like a tool palette). One approach is to connect
>   each button's clicked() signal to its own custom slot; but in this
>   example we want to connect all the buttons to a single slot and
>   parameterize the slot by the button that was clicked.

So imagine you have a number of buttons encapsulated in a class, say `ButtonWidget`, with a custom signal `void clicked(const QString &text)`. Here is the definition:

```
class ButtonWidget : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  ButtonWidget(QStringList texts, QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:
  void clicked(const QString &text);

private:
  QSignalMapper *signalMapper;
};
```

The constructor could then be defined like the following:

```
ButtonWidget::ButtonWidget(QStringList texts, QWidget *parent)
  : QWidget(parent)
{
  signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

  QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout;
  for (int i = 0; i < texts.size(); ++i) {
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(texts[i]);
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    signalMapper->setMapping(button, texts[i]);
    gridLayout->addWidget(button, i / 3, i % 3);
  }

  connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(const QString &)),
          this, SIGNAL(clicked(const QString &)));

  setLayout(gridLayout);
}
```

So what happens here? We construct a grid layout and our buttons of type `QPushButton`. The `clicked()` signal of each of these is connected to the signal mapper.

One of the forces using `QSignalMapper` is that you can pass arguments to the re-emitted signals. In our example each of the buttons should emit a different text (due to the definition of our signal), so we set this using the `setMapping()` method.

Now all that's left to do is map the signal mapper to the signal of our class:

```
connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(const QString &)),
        this, SIGNAL(clicked(const QString &)));
```

Assume we have a testing class called `TestClass` then `ButtonWidget` can be used thusly:

```
TestClass::TestClass() {
  widget = new ButtonWidget(QStringList() << "Foo" << "Bar");
  connect(widget, SIGNAL(clicked(const QString &)),
          this, SLOT(onButtonClicked(const QString &)));
}

void TestClass::onButtonClicked(const QString &btnText) {
  if (btnText == "Foo") {
    // Do stuff.
  }
  else {
    // Or something else.   
  }
}
```

By using the signal mapper this way you don't have to declare and manage all the buttons and their clicked signals, just one signal pr. `ButtonWidget`.

The buttom line is that the signal mapper is great for bundling multiple signals and you can even set parameters when it re-emits them. I hope that gave some intuition about the usage of `QSignalMapper`.

---

**Your example code**

The explanation (your "para") states that all the actions are each individually mapped to a specific `QWidget*`. When triggering an action its respective `QWidget*` will be passed to the slot `QWorkspace::setActiveWindow(QWidget*)` of `workspace`, which in turn activates the widget.

Also note that the mapping from action to widget has to happen somewhere in your code. I assume it is done in `createActions()` or `enableActions()` perhaps.

Comment: In the code `connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));` what's the type of `button` object? , if `ButtonWidget` then as you already said `ButtonWidget` doesn't have any signal `connect()` instead a custom signal `void clicked(const QString &text)` . also your code `signalMapper->setMapping(button, texts[i]);` and it's corresponding explanation which was explained above the code per se.

Comment: Are you rep whoring? . You see I'm reading a beginners book so please support your theory with simple, small and complete examples rather than plain theory. How does above example of your solves the issue etc would be awesome add-ons. Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the documentation page that I pointed out? It shows the complete example with types, too. In their example the internal buttons are of type `QPushButton` that has the signal `connect()`. Yes, so afterwards you have an instance of `ButtonWidget` from which you connect the signal with the string to a slot, and react to the different buttons in a single method instead of a slot for each of them. `setMapping()` sets the parameter that will be passed along when the `clicked()` signal is triggered in our case.

Comment: And no, I'm not rep whoring. I'm trying to help you out here. My example shows how a signal mapper can be used to simplify code, but I will just make it more clear to you in my post.

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed answer and help now, Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

A [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html) allows you to add some information to a signal, when you need it. This object internally have a map like `QMap<QObject*,QVariant>`. Then you connect an object to it, and when the slot is called, it re-emit the signal with the associated value.

Workflow:

```
mySignalMapper:
    [ obj1 -> 42       ]
    [ obj2 -> "obiwan" ]
    [ obj3 -> myWidget ]

connect(obj1,mySignal,mySignalMapper,SLOT(map())); // idem for obj2 and obj3

(obj2 emits "mySignal")
-> (mySignalMapper::map slot is called)
-> (sender() == obj2, associated data = "obiwan")
-> (mySignalMapper emits mapped("obiwan"))
```

I was going to add a more detailed example, but Morten Kristensen was faster than me ;)